# Why is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}(r-1)^{n-i}{n\choose i} = r^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I was solving a problem and found that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}2^{n-i}{n\choose i} = 3^n$. So I tried to generalise it and got $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}(r-1)^{n-i}{n\choose i} = r^n$. Is it true for $r > 1, r \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It's the binomial theorem i.e. $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^n$ with $x=r-1$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I feel like an idiot asking the question. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Note that 
$$r^n=\{(r-1)+1\}^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\cdot (r-1)^{n-i}\cdot 1^i.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider counting $r$-tuples of sets $(A_1,\dots,A_r)$ such that $A_1 \subseteq \dots \subseteq A_r$. The number of such is clearly $r^n$ since we may view it as choosing which of the sets $A_1, A_2 \setminus A_1, \dots, A_r \setminus A_{r-1}, [n]\setminus A_r$ each element of $[n]$ belongs to.  The left hand side is conditioning on what bottom set we take (i.e., what $A_1$ is).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {{n}\choose{i}}x^iy^{n-i}$$